# Bernini did what, exactly, with St. Peter's Basilica's entrance?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

The story goes as follows:

Nearly a century after the construction of St. Peter's Basilica, Bernini (sculptor and architect, the author of many of Rome's fountains and designer of Barberini's Palace, among other things) was called upon by Pope Alexander VII to make further improvements to the church.

As he studied the Basilica from various angles and distances, it occurred to Bernini that he could not see the dome at all if he stood too close to the facade. This struck him as a major design flaw.

In order to rectify the situation without rebuilding the Basilica from the ground up, Bernini designed the now famous piazza in front of it, with a colonnade encircling it.

Thus, psychologically, the main entrance of the Basilica was "relocated" from the actual Basilica to the entrance of the piazza, where the dome was in full view, Bernini's idea being that the piazza served as some sort of anteroom of the Basilica.

This sounds awfully awkward and confusing unless illustrated by a picture:

[image]

How would you describe what Bernini did? What word, or words, would you use to get the point across without falling back on visual aids?

Bernini devised a ... what? ... [pretend? new, psychological?] entrance? 
The plaza's ... what? ... entrance? ... became the Basilica's new entrance? ...

There's a couple of words I'm missing here. I'm pretty sure they're fairly common, straight-forward ones, I just can't remember what they are.

Comment: Is it a story or a legend? "*The elliptical center of the piazza, which contrasts with the trapezoidal entrance, encloses the visitor with "the maternal arms of Mother Church" in Bernini's expression.*" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Peter%27s_Square

Comment: @Josh: It's history.

Comment: @Josh: The Basilica is Renaissance. The colonnade is Baroque.

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand what you are looking for. "A perspective entrance" perhaps?

Comment: @Josh: Something like it, I guess. I'm not sure. Hence the question.

Comment: @Josh: I'm mostly looking for a way to phrase the above clearly and succinctly. As opposed to vaguely and wordily.

Comment: The outdoor entryway creates an oversized *three-dimensional matting* for the artwork (St. Peter's) that, as for any art, adds importance to it. Also, the plaza prevents any future construction that could block the magnificent view.

Comment: @YosefBaskin: Not bad, by Jove! But it's only marginally related to the original point, I'm afraid.

Comment: Bernini devised an extended entrance to force a desired perspective (and experience) on visitors.

Comment: @Davo +1 for not giving your excellent suggestion as an 'answer' to what is a question of very borderline acceptability. 'Is there a word for relocating what may be regarded as an 'entrance' to improve the view of a structure from the 'entrance' by  adding extra distance with no added obstacles?' Asking for an extended answer is off-topic because it seeks writing advice.

Comment: @Josh: "A perspective entrance" is an interesting idea. Thank you. Let me think about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In architectural terminology, it is known as a type of [**foreportal**](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1481844?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) / [**fore-portal**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=foreportal).

In *De Officiis Libre Tres*, by Marcus Tullius Cicero, c.1852 version, in the notes on p.175 for Chapter XVII, we find reference to,

> the entrance to the Acropolis, the [fore-portal](https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=nZAZAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&pg=GBS.PA174) of the Parthenon.

A later, c.1859 edition of the same work, uses the term [vestibule](https://ia800603.us.archive.org/8/items/deofficiislibrit00ci/deofficiislibrit00ci.pdf) with the Greek term, TvpoTcvkaia given as the translation. However, Google Translate gives a slightly different translation for vestibule, [προθάλαμος](https://translate.google.com/#en/el/vestibule)

[image: vestibule (c.1859 translation from the Greek)]

[image: fore-portal (c.1852 translation)]

[Foreportal](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=Foreportal) is an architectural term used a number of times in both the 19th and 20th centuries, the [***Royal Dictionary***](https://books.google.com/books?id=uCNKAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA87&dq=Foreportal&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiO7ZHc9dPZAhUR6GMKHUOlDEc4RhDoAQgtMAE#v=onepage&q=Foreportal&f=false), c.1866, directly equating **fore-portal** with the French term, **avant-portail**. Googling [avant-portail](http://www.ebay.fr/itm/CPA-N-B-VIERGE-ROUEN-N-263-Cour-des-Libraires-Avant-portail-NDPhot-/321343693420) reveals that it refers to the outer front gate of a structure, usually a church or cathedral.

[image: avant-portail]

The characterization given in the 1852 version of Cicero's work, of the [Acropolis](http://www.emersonkent.com/map_archive/acropolis_200_ad.htm) acting as a [**fore-portal / foreportal**](https://books.google.com/books?id=1RIAeAMUJywC&pg=PA527&dq=Foreportal&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZufHm_NPZAhUH3WMKHdm4C-gQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=Foreportal&f=false) for the Parthenon fits very logically with the feature described in this question, of the outer courtyard entrance to St. Peter's Basilica. Both structures are considered sacred architecture, featuring open-air surrounds forming types of courtyards, with ceremonious front gates and grand pathways leading to the main doors of the religious structures containing the altars.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In French I would refer to this as a *mise en valeur* of the dome, a phrase that has no exact English equivalent.

However, a [search for English translations](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/mise+en+valeur.html) of *mise en valeur* led to some possible words you could use:

- beautify
- develop
- emphasize
- enhance
- showcase
- show off
- present (or maybe re-present)

I have seen the expression translated into English as *valorize*, but to my mind this is too ugly a word for something like the piazza.

Maybe the [Italian expression itself](http://context.reverso.net/traduction/francais-italien/mettre+en+valeur) would serve your purpose, e.g. **valorizzare** or **mettere in valore**.  Sometimes the original is your best bet.

For the specific action that Bernini performed on the physical entrance, it's hard to improve on your original term of "relocated".